# No crontab for user when trying to set up cronjob in command line

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, reindex, crontab

I'm a total newbie here, and I need some help. I'd just installed **Magento 2.1.3**, and I got this

> message: "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento
>   cron job is running."

I've tried to follow the instructions found in the link below, but when I come to the part where it involves crontab and a text editor, the console says that there is no cron tab found for the user that I'm logged in as.

HOW do I get around this?
Appreciate your help :)
Thanks in advance!
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new crontab entry with this command :

```
crontab -u magento-user -e
```

The Magento user can be your webserver such as www-data or apache2 or another user. The user should have the right to write on some Magento folders.